# Writing RSpec to isolate and test specific methods in class

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

What would be the best approach to write unit tests for a gem that uses classes? I've written a gem that does things that includes external integrations during initialization. While writing tests, I don't want to initialize everything, I just want to test certain functions.

For example, I have `lib/foomon.rb`:

```
class FooMon
  def initialize
    @log = Logger.new("app.log","daily")
    pollingClient = SomePoller.new(remote_service_url)
    pollingClient.poll do |response|
       processResponse(response)
    end
  end

  private 

  def processResponse(res)
    {:response => res.body}
  end
end
```

Now I want to test the `processResponse` function. The approach I'm taking is to remove the `private` modifier and then move the code from `initialize` to a new `setup` method. The main entry point of the app then calls setup, but my tests don't (they only have a `@foomon = FooMon.new` in `before`). The spec can then test `@foomon.processResponse`

Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

When I've done this in the past, I've tended to use [RSpec Mocks (doubles)](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs). In your particular case, a double that stubs `#body` would do the trick, I think.

```
RSpec.describe FooMon do
  before do
    @foomon = FooMon.new
  end

  it "should process the response" do
    response = instance_double("Response")
    expect(response).to receive(:body).once.and_return("I ain't got no body ...")

    expect {response_body = @foomon.send(:process_response, response)}.not_to raise_error
    expect response_body == "I ain't got no body ..."
  end
end
```

Disclaimer: written in a browser, from aging memory. May need debugging.

Here's the best [real-life, working example](https://github.com/purp/mtif/blob/master/spec/mtif_spec.rb) I can lay my hands on. Hopefully that helps provide some color.

Answer (score 1):

The specs should only test public methods, if you remove the private modifier of this class in fact `processResponce`can be tested otherwise there is nothing to test there.

In regards of the external integrations of the class, in a unit testing approach, you should only test what return from the class itself.

In this case, you should only test what is return from `processResponce`, all the logic generated by the other classes like `Logger` and `SomePoller` should be tested on other specs and not in this one.

In this case, I suggest to change the logic that is in the initializer and move it to a separated public method. So that method can have the responsibility of sending the message to the client and be easier to test.

You can mock the behavior of those classes using a `double`. Like this:

```
let(:poller) { double(:poller)
let(:responce) { double(:responce, body: "message") }

before do
  allow(poller).to receive(:poll).and_yield(responce)
  allow(SomePoller).to response(:new) { poller }
end

it 'send a message to the client' do
  expect(response).to receive(:body).once
  subject.send_client
end
```

With that, you can only test the class responsibilities and note makes your test too complex.

References:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-6/docs/
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/yielding#yield-an-argument